# Python3: how to use for loop to get values from two list

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

My code:

```
i=[o for o in range(10000)]
ii=[o for o in range(10000,20000)]

for a,b in i,ii:
    print(a,b)
```

But the above code returns error (too many values to unpack)

I want to get the result as:

```
1 10001
2 10002
 ...........
10000 20000
```

I want to use this to create a download and upload parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip`

```
i=[o for o in range(10000)]
ii=[o for o in range(10000,20000)]

for a,b in zip(i,ii):
    print(a,b)
```

*Shorter*

```
for a,b in zip(range(10000), range(10000,20000)):
    print(a,b)
```

Comment: For the lists you provided, I am not sure if you need two lists. Following generates only one array of numbers:
 `for a in range(10000):
      print(a,a+10000)`